# MongoDB Cannot use a complex object as a key value Java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, graph, spring-data-mongodb

I'm implementing an object that represents a graph to be stored in a MongoDb. Here's the class definition:

```
@Document(collection = "mygraph")
public class MyGraph {

    @Id
    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    public String id;
    public Map<Instance, Set<Instance>> graph;
    public String timestamp;

    /**
     * Add the default constructor
     */
    public MyGraph() {
        this.id = new ObjectId().toHexString();
        this.graph = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        this.timestamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    }

        /**
     * 
     * @param instances
     */
    public MyGraph(Set<Instance> instances) {
        this.id = new ObjectId().toHexString();
        this.graph = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        this.timestamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());

        /* Initialize the graph */
        for (Instance instance : instances) {
            this.graph.put(instance, new HashSet<>());
        }
    }
    // get and set method are below
}
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
Time elapsed: 0.03 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Cannot use a complex object as a key value.
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeMapInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:669)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.createMap(MappingMongoConverter.java:585)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:471)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:430)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:418)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:312)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:418)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:392)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:356)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.toDbObject(MongoTemplate.java:853)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doSave(MongoTemplate.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:963)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.save(SimpleMongoRepository.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy197.save(Unknown Source)
    at models.CloudGraphTest.testSaveCloudGraph(CloudGraphTest.java:79)
```

How can I change my `MappingMongoConverter` to accomodate for that?

Comment: Where is your MappingMongoConverter ? Did you already write one and is not working ? Where is your CloudGraphTest class ?

Answer (score 1):

There's an open Improvement in Spring: [Don't require Converters for Complex classes that are used as Ids](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-485).

Unfortunately, currently Spring team decided not to support it.

> decided not to support it at all

**EDIT**

There's an open related issue [Allow using complex types as Map keys](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-242) that may include a fix later